# DataTables with own Search Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I use DataTables because I don't want to create my own multi-functional table with paging.

I use standard jQuery Ajax request to post my data in my own form. After the user submit the form, my Ajax will return something like this `Data. Then I call basic DataTables function to beautify the table.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxSearch.php",
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(returnData) {
        if(returnData.Type == 'success') {
            $('#tbody').html(returnData.Message);
            $('#table').DataTable({
                paging: true,
                searching: false,
                lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, 50, 100], [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]],
                iDisplayLength: 5,
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: true,
                    targets: -1
                }]
            });
        }       
    },
});
```

Then I found some <s>bugs</s> compatibility issues that DataTables doesn't control well to my listing table. I know DataTables has a Server-side Process but I have my own form and I have my own MySQLi class. I don't wanna modify much to complete the same task.

As I found the issue I decided to change my code design. The basic requirement is to keep my own Ajax searching form (normal HTML), my own MySQLi class to return an Ajax that fits DataTables requirement.

I think DataTables needs this type of Ajax:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [
        [
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "System Architect",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09",
            "$2,875"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton",
            "Cox",
            "Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "12th Jan 09",
            "$4,800"
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Please let me know the new jQuery function and how to generate "draw", "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" and "data" in normal while loop of `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Thanks.

---

**What my Ajax (returnData) returns:**

```
{
    "Type" : "success",
    "Message": 
        "<tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>John Smith</td>
           <td><a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>John Doe</td>
           <td><a href="edit.php?id=2">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>"
}
```

It is just HTML code to construct my table, then I call dataTables to beautify my table.

---

Full Table (tbody is returned from Ajax), then I called DataTable.
**Before returning from Ajax:**

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**After Ajax fills:**

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
       <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>John Smith</td>
          <td><a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>John Doe</td>
          <td><a href="edit.php?id=2">Edit</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This catches my eye first:

```
if(returnData.Type == 'success') {
   $('#tbody').html(returnData.Message);
 }
```

It would appear that after you use dataTables to format your nice table, the very next thing you do is to use jQuery to select the '#tbody' of your table and obliterate it with the contents of `returnData.Message`.

Next, you do not need to generate 'draw', 'recordsTotal' and 'recordsFiltered' unless you are using the dataTables `serverSide: true` option.

The `serverSide` [option defaults to `false`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) so unless you have declared it as `true`, you don't have to worry about modifying your data object to include those 3 paramaters you mentioned.

Also, the `iDisplayLength` [param is deprecated](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#iDisplayLength), and may not work with your current version of dataTables, which is???

To help you further, please share an example of the data payload that your server returns, and a screenshot of what is rendering to your page afterwards.

---

Thank you for sharing the formatting of the table and the returnData.Message. I've made the [following codepen to illustrate](http://codepen.io/lexjacobs/pen/zGepdY) the rendered form of your dataTable.

Please clarify what your issue is. If I were to guess, I might think it has something to do with the fact that after you continue to change the DOM with your server calls, your dataTable doesn't actually hold on to any of the changes if you do something like sorting or a page-change. Is this correct?

One thing you could do would be to completely remove your dataTable from the dom before you re-apply your server results to your original table html.

You can do so like this:

```
   if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#table")) {
     oTable = $("#table").DataTable();
     oTable.destroy({remove:true});
   }
```

And after you completely remove your dataTable, if you re-append your original table html, then append your server response, then initialize the table with dataTables, you should have a working table.

You can see on the codepen that the dataTables initialization has handled pagination, as the 8 entries are more than the "show 5 entries" in the selector, and you don't have to worry about the "draw" "recordsTotal" or "recordsFiltered".

[image: codepen results]

Please see codepen for working example.

Comment: Well, the version of dataTables should be 1.10.7. And I have added to returned Ajax in my question.

Comment: Do you already have the <th> elements in your HTML? It would also be helpful to see your HTML. And you will need to append returnData.Message to the table *before* initializing your dataTable on the #table. Another test you can do while you are troubleshooting is to just call $('#table').dataTable() without any parameters. You can fill those in later after you have the basic dataTable working.

Comment: also see this for explanation between dataTable() and DataTable(): https://datatables.net/faqs/#api

Comment: I have a `<thead><tr><th> ... </th></tr></thead>` before `<tbody> ... </tbody>`. I also return `returnData.Message` inside the `<tbody></tbody>` tag before calling DataTables().

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell much from this in-line comment. Please share the complete formatting of your existing table html. And it would be helpful to share what your html looks like *before* and *after* the server returns the returnData.Message so we can see if there is any formatting problem. I will try on my computer to initialize a dataTable() to the complete html after I can see it. Perhaps make a github gist, or codepen. Thank you.